# HTML set fixed value if max limit is reached

Tags: html, limit

I've searched SO a bit for the same issue, but I could only find 'sort of solutions' like max & maxlength, but these won't work for me.

HTML that I have:

```
<input type="text" id="current" name="current_xj" maxlength="9" placeholder="Enter your value">
```

I want to set the maximum at: 200000000.
I thought I could use max="200000000" but it doesn't work for me.

```
<input type="text" id="current" name="current_xj" maxlength="9" max="200000000" placeholder="Enter your value">
```

You can still enter the number 250000000 or 999999999, I tend to do some live calculations. So it doesn't validate if the number is higher then 200000000.

What I want to do is:
Option 1)
If somebody enters a number higher then 200000000, then change the input value to 200000000. Instantly, since there is no button to click (like submit or calculate or anything).

Option 2)
Don't allow any number higher then 200000000 being input.

How would I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code which will trigger the function when the value becomes greater

```js
function func() {
  if (document.getElementById("current").value > 200000000) {
    //alert("reached max limit");
    document.getElementById("current").value = 200000000;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="current" name="current_xj" maxlength="9" onkeyup="func()" placeholder="Enter your value">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() < 200000000) {

    } else {
      alert("Reached Maximun Limit of Input");
      $(this).val() = 200000000;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Validate text Box</h4>
  <input type="text" id="current" name="current_xj" maxlength="9" max="200000000" placeholder="Enter your value">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some JQuery test you could continue on developing

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".Int").keydown(function() {
    try {
      var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
      $(this).attr("Temp", value) // Save the current value
    } catch (err) {

    }

  }).keyup(function() {

    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var temp = $(this).attr("Temp");
    var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));
    // if the new value bigger then max, then load the prev value
    if (value > max)
      $(this).val(temp);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="current" class="Int" name="current_xj" maxlength="9" max="200000000" placeholder="Enter your value">
```